# Favicon not showing on quick links on Android Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

The way I use to display the favicon on my website is to add a favicon.ico in the root folder.
It is working alright on the tabs of the desktop and also the tabs on Chrome in phone itself, but when it's in the quick links, I only see the first letter of my website name. so if the domain is `example.com` I see E instead of the favicon:
[image]

Will I have to add meta tag for favicon to make it show here, or it has nothing to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`favicon.ico` is used for low resolution icons, such as the one that appears in the tab. However, bookmark and add-to-home-screen images must be high resolution icons.

In order to have such icons for Android Chrome:

- Preferably, provide a [Web App Manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/), along with a 192x192 icon.
- If you don't want to create such file, you can provide a [180x180 Apple Touch icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html). It is simpler and more platforms support it (eg. iOS Safari).

As an alternative, you can use online favicon generators, such as [RealFaviconGenerator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/), to create all these files for you. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this service.